# Can I develop Linux based Raspberry Pi apps in Visual Studio 2015 or on a Mac (Eclipse or XCode)?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2

I know there's a lot you can do in VS2015 as far as cross platform mobile dev, but I am not sure if it can do Linux, specifically for the Raspberry Pi Raspbian OS.
Can it?

If not, can I use something like Eclipse on my Mac or something else on my Windows machine?

I've done some mobile work before in iOS and a tiny bit of exploration in Droid so I imagine it's close to one of those.

Comment: why the down-votes?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** you can.

Raspian is a pretty complete OS, so you could run apps compiled by any language like Python/node/C/C++/C#. (Raspberry Pi 2 can now run Ubuntu)

**Run Windows Apps**

The easiest way to do it would be to load Windows IoT Core onto Raspberry Pi and create UWP apps in Visual Studio. This gives you remote deployment, debugging and powerful APIs from the get go. [Windows Iot Core for Raspberry Pi](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm)

**Python & Node**

Write in VS using 
[nodejstools](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools)
[python tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx)
Then you just copy paste the code to rpi, and run it using node/python

**C/C++**

Simply use VS to develop, and build using the [Windows toolchain for Raspberry Pi](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/tutorial/).

**C#**

I haven't played around it too much, try [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the directions to take.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the "[Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e)" extension for Visual studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

I use my Raspberry Pi to write desktop programs in C#.Net. I use Mono to run the program and MonoDevelop to write it. Mono supports using System.Windows.Forms on the Raspberry Pi, but MonoDevelop only supports GTK for a gui. To use System.Windows.Forms, you need to code it directly instead of dropping controls on a form.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete

sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Needed for debugging of console applications:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```